# Photoshop: Copy and paste an image without trimming transparency

Tags: photoshop, copy-paste

I have an image fo this kind:

1000x1000 but only a portion of the image is opaque, think a filled circle on the left, other picels are transparent.

I want to copy/paste only a portion of the image with an area choosed by me:

I drag and drop the mouse so that part will be 400x100 but when i paste i have an image 300x76. 
photoshop has trimmed my image, but i want it with the border of the image choosed by me, i want that coordinates.
preparing an image 400x100 blank and copying that image doesn't solve my problem because i must pan the image on the original position.

how can i copy/paste the image without trimming?
thanks

Comment: Photoshop... whats that.. I make the codes

Comment: its image editing / image making software for web

Comment: Can we move it to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and re-open it please? It's a very good question, and pops up as a first answer in google.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is because you're asking Photoshop to take into account an area that doesn't exist (it's transparent). You cannot "Copy" an area where nothing exists in Photoshop. Your only option is to place something (a colour) in the corners where the transparency exists, select your area, Copy Merged (using CTRL + SHIFT + C) and then delete the extra colour once you've pasted it.

There's no other way around it.

Comment: That sucks :( I just spent an hour creating a selection of actions which automate the expansion of a particular tileset format, but when transparency exists around the edges the pasted parts of the image are aligned incorrectly.

Photoshop *could* offer an option to do this, however, because transparent pixels are usually represented by the RGBA colour (0, 0, 0, 0). It is a pitty that there is no such option.

Comment: @LeaHayes Yeah, you're right. I'm surprised there isn't an option to preserve transparencies now that I think about it. Hmm!

Comment: Corner colors are great idea! You saved me many hours ! :) (Im creating interactive map right now -_-

Comment: _>>to take into account an area that doesn't exist (it's transparent). You cannot "Copy" an area where nothing exists<<_. That is actually wrong. Techically and practically you still can save all available colours in 100% transparent pixels. So these transparent areas/pixels exist and are only getting removed/lost by most of drawing software. And to the topic: Paint.NET is not cropping transparent pixels when copying areas :P

Answer (score -4):

it depends by which method you are doing copy paste.

i suggest you to use marquee tool.

select marquee tool
drag it to your desired area,now copy and than paste it.,if its not copying the thing press cntrl+shift+c because most of the time,Photoshop memory don't behave dynamically.

Comment: This is nonsense. CTRL + SHIFT + C tells Photoshop to copy from ALL layers, not just the selected one. It's got nothing to do with "dynamically behaving memory", and it doesn't help in this situation. The problem this user is having is because he's selecting a transparent area that PS is ignoring... because there's nothing in it.

Comment: i dont think so ctrl+shift+c do copy from all layer it depends what version and shorcut setting you have.

Comment: No it doesn't. I've been using Photoshop professionally for the past 10 years, in many different versions. Anyways, the question is closed now, so it's all moot.